# How can I subscribe to a message being sent to the _skipped queue in rabbit mq

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

Question one: Can I subscribe to the event of a message being sent to the _skipped queue?

I am using masstransit together with rabbit mq. Some messages sometimes are sent to the _skipped queue for unclear reasons. The message type has a consumer, the ttl (time to life) is not small. It should not happen, and I am getting a log entry from masstransit, but I want to do more at the moment. Maybe log an error, in test maybe pop-up a window. Is there a way to achieve this? I am only getting these log messages below.

MassTransit.ReceiveTransport|SKIP rabbitmq://localhost/services_admin db270000-1fd6-00ff-3b83-08d9000ef97c
MassTransit.ReceiveTransport|Declare queue: name: services_admin_skipped, durable, consumer-count: 0 message-count: 3

Question two: What exactly happens to messages in the _skipped queue? Can they be resent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skipped messages either don't match the type (namespace included), don't have a consumer on the endpoint, or were a response to a request client that is no longer waiting for it. Since it's a receive endpoint queue, it's likely one of the first two reasons. Look at the message body/details in the RabbitMQ Management Console, that should give you some ideas.

You can use a shovel in RabbitMQ to move the messages back into the queue once you've resolved the issue.